# infix to postfix conversion in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

so here I have a code for infix to postfix conversion. The idea is to send a string which contains an infix formula and to return postfix notation of that formula. The operaators are `+ - * / () [] {}` and function `tezinaOperacije()` returns 1 if the operation is `+` or `-` and 2 if operation is `*` or `/`. Else it return -1. And the function `zatvorenaZagrada()` returns the right closed bracket when you call it on an opened bracket. The problem is that function returns an empty string. Can someone help please?

```
string infixToPostfix(string& str){
        stack<char> stek;
        string s="";
        for(int i=0; i<str.size(); i++){
            s+=s[i];
        }
        char pre='(';
        string copy="";
        for(int i=0; i<s.size(); i++){
            if(s[i]>='0' && s[i]<='9'){
                if(pre==')' || prei==']' || pre=='}' || pre=='0') throw "wrong";
                char number=s[i];
                copy+=number;
                pre=='0';
            }
            else if(s[i]=='(' || s[i]=='[' || s[i]=='{'){
                        if(pre=='0' || pre==')') throw "Wrong";
                        char sign=s[i];
                        stek.push(sign);
                        pre=sign;
                    }
            else if(s[i]==')' || s[i]==']' || s[i]=='}'){
                char sign=s[i];
                while(!stek.empty() && tezinaOperacije(stek.top())>0){
                    copy+=stek.top();
                    stek.pop();
                }
                if(stek.empty() || sign !=ZatvorenaZagrada(stek.top())) throw "wrong declaration";
                stek.pop();
                pre=sign;
            }
            else if(tezinaOperacije(s[i])>0){
                char sign=s[i];
                if(tezinaOperacije(pre)>0 || pre=='(' || pre=='[' || pre=='{') throw "wrong";
                while(!stek.empty() && tezinaOperacije(stek.top())>=tezinaOperacije(sign)){
                    copy+=stek.top();
                    stek.pop();
                }
                stek.push(sign);
                pre=sign;
            }
        }
        while(!stek.empty()){
            copy+=stek.top();
            stek.pop();
        }
        return copy;
    }
```

Comment: Have you used a debugger to step through your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With

```
    string s="";
    for(int i=0; i<str.size(); i++){
        s+=s[i];
//---------^  s?
    }
```

you obtain a `s` full of zero (`'\0'`)

I suppose your intention was

```
    string s="";
    for(int i=0; i<str.size(); i++){
        s+=str[i];
//---------^^^
    }
```

With `s` full of zero, the following `for`

```
    for(int i=0; i<s.size(); i++){
        if(s[i]>='0' && s[i]<='9'){
          // ...
        }
        else if(s[i]=='(' || s[i]=='[' || s[i]=='{'){
          // ...
        }
        else if(s[i]==')' || s[i]==']' || s[i]=='}'){
          // ...
        }
        else if(tezinaOperacije(s[i])>0){
          // ...
        }
    }
```

make nothing useful and `copy` remain empty.

Comment: yes, I meant s+=str[i], but still I have a problem. It seems that the first "if" doesn't take number in my string, so the last "else if" throws exception

Comment: @sneh - maybe because `pre` is `(` and `if ( ... || pre == '(' || ... ) throw "wrong"` ?

Comment: but that is the last thing that program checks. Int the first if, program would have to recognize that first character of string is a number.